# how to display the results as image button in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, imagebutton

I have some results stored in array, validated from JavaScript.

I want it to be displayed as image buttons, so that, on selecting the image button it can navigate to another page.

Comment: can you show the expected o/p and what you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE. Click the `<>` and post a [mcve]